# Set correctly the number of items by raw in Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have one weird issue into my Woocommerce store. When I check [in  my shop](http://extensionuwholesale.com/shop/) via desktop, all seems OK, but when check from smartphone, show me only 3 product items, others are missing. 
I Tried to scroll down, but nothing happens. I have noticed that item blocks don't wrap into parent block, and continue to be displayed inline, like desktop version.

[image]

**EDIT** I found this CSS:

```
.woocommerce ul.products {
display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
```

When removing:

```
display: flex;
```

… it show all categories, but one bellow one, and I want to show **three** columns on desktop and **one** column in on smartphones.

How Can I do that?

Can someone to tell me where is issue, because I haven't be able to solve this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme the products are set to be displayed in 2 columns when looking to the html structure:

- each **odd** `<li>` has "first" class
- each **even** `<li>` has "last" class

So yes you should remove those **wrong** CSS rules:

```css
.woocommerce ul.products {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Or override them inserting the following CSS rule in `styles.css` file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*:

```css
.woocommerce ul.products {
    display: block !important;
}
```

> And try to find out **in your theme** for woocommerce **settings** regarding the **number of items by row** to be displayed.

Or using this [classic code snippet](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-number-of-products-per-row/), that will set 3 product by row:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 3; // 3 products per row
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

Tested and works.

> Never use CSS `display:flex` for Woocommerce archive pages like shop on items.

---

**Edit:** To get your product on 2 columns on smartphones (below 480px) add this to the `styles.css` file of your active child theme *(or active theme)* at the end of the file:

```css
@media (max-width: 480px){
    .woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
        float: left !important;
        width: 48.05% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I inseted CSS you provided into Custom CSS, and inserted funtion into functions.php, but now show me 2 columns per side, and on mobile view, show me all one by one.. This is how is set into my theme about product archives. https://i.imgur.com/SLly47i.png?1

Comment: Thanks. On homepage now works fine, but on mobile view still show me one category bellow other.. So how to make there also to have 3 columns?

Comment: Sorry @LoicTheAztec.. Now is fixed. Pls check